# Method binding - What if Method is in another Class/Namespace?

Tags: wpf, xaml, namespaces

Let's say I got the following ComboBox in my XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbOinkOink" Loaded="cmbOinkOink_Loaded" />
```

And I have my cmbOinkOink_Loaded method deep in here:

```
namespace PiggyWPF.Classes.EventHandler
{

    class ComboBoxEventHandler
    {

        public void cmbOinkOink_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do Stuff...
        }
    }

}
```

How am I going to tell XAML that the cmbOinkOink_Loaded is going to be found under PiggyWPF.Classes.EventHandler.ComboBoxEventHandler?

Comment: Why do you want to handle like that? Are you trying to handle the loaded event of a combobox in one view in some other view? Use command to achieve that.

Comment: @ViVi The ComboBoxHandler will contain more methods soon. The ComboBox is under PiggyWPF.MainWindow. I just want to place all the ComboBox-involving methods under PiggyWPF.Classes.EventHandler.ComboBoxEventHandler.

Comment: Are you following the MVVM pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is a straight forward way to achieve this behavior from xaml.
but you can do this easily from code behind.

```
class Control
{
...
public void cmbOinkOink_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       _handlerObject.DoStuff();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to forward the method call one way or another, either via the code behind of that XAML that defines the `ComboBox` or by using e.g. the `ExecuteCommandAction` from Interactivity, which requires you to provide a [command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx) in you original class instead of just a method, ideally static or otherwise easily accessible so you can use `x:Static` or something similar in the action's XAML.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP).*

I guess my only way was to add the following code to my main class:

```
private void cmbOinkOink_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (ComboBoxEventHandler cmbEvent = new ComboBoxEventHandler())
        {
            cmbEvent.cmbOinkOink_Loaded(ref sender, e);
        }
    }
```